# Rails/Authlogic: Logging out on timeout - multiple databases are used

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, authlogic

I'd like to log the user out after a certain period of inactivity. This is easy enough in Authlogic, however my application is set up so a different database is used each annual quarter. Users have the ability to switch quarters, so when they do, the :last_request_at field will always be old, thus instantly logging them out.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to do the logic yourself by storing it in a cookie (a session variable). Just add a last_request session variable and update it each time they make a request. If it's out of date, log them out. Since it's stored on the client, it won't matter if you switch databases.